# How to Implement DataTable in ASP.Net Core MVC6

Tags: asp.net-core, datatables, asp.net-core-3.0

I have converted my application from ASP.Net MVC 5 web application to ASP.Net Core MVC 6. In the MVC 5, I implemented DataTables Server Side Processing successfully. However in the ASP.Net Core, I keep getting

> **Error 404 (Not Found)**.

Previewing the error in the Network session of my browser, I get

> HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found
>   The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.

Below is my grid view

```
@model _AuditDTGridViewModel
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" id="datatab">
    <thead id="sortableHeader" class="bg-grey">
        <tr id="columnFilterRow" class="filter" style="">
            @foreach (var c in Model.ColumnOptions)
            {
            <td>
                @if (c.ShowColumnSearchField)
                {
                if (c.ColumnSearchFieldType.ToLower() == "text")
                {
                <input id="filtercolumn_@c.ColumnName" class="input-xsmall" type="text" style="width: 100% !important" />
                }
                }
                else if (c.DisplayName == "Actions")
                {
                @*<button id="filterColumnSearchBtn" class="btn btn-xs btn-outline green" title="Search Columns" style="border-width: 1px!important; margin-bottom: 2px"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Search</button>*@
                <button id="clearfilterColumnSearchBtn" class="btn btn-xs btn-outline red" title="Reset Filter" style="border-width: 1px!important"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>Clear Filter</button>
                }
            </td>
            }
        </tr>
        <tr id="sortableHeading" class="heading">
            @foreach (var c in Model.ColumnOptions)
            {
            <th>
                @Html.Raw(c.DisplayName)
            </th>

            }
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var oTable = $('#datatab').DataTable({
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "type": "POST",
            "url": '@Url.Action("AjaxListOfAudits", "Client", Model)',
            "contentType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'data': function (data) {
                return data = JSON.stringify(data);
            }
        },
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "processing": true,
        "paging": true,
        "deferRender": true,
        "columns": @Html.Raw(Model.data),
    "order": [1, "asc"]
    });
</script>
```

And in my controller, I'm calling the action below

```
public JsonResult AjaxListOfAudits(_AuditDTGridViewModel _AuditDTGridViewModel, DTParameters param)
{
    // Some codes go here
}
```

Here is my _AuditDTGridViewModel

```
public class _AuditDTGridViewModel : BaseSearchFilterViewModel
    {
        public _AuditDTGridViewModel()
            : base()
        {
            AllAuditsOrMyAudits = 1;
        }

        public Dictionary<string, string> AuditType { get; set; }
        public int? MembershipId { get; set; }
        public int AllAuditsOrMyAudits { get; set; }
        public int? AuditAction { get; set; }
        public int? AuditCategory { get; set; }
        public string data { get; set; }
        public List<DTColumnOptions> ColumnOptions { get; set; }
    }
```

When I try to debug, the action is not being hit. If I remove the Model from the Url Action, I get

> Error 400 - Bad Request

1. What Am I doing wrong in the dotnet core that I'm getting that Not Found error?
2. If this approach of passing the model in the query is wrong in dotnet core, how do I do it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.

In your code, we can find you are passing your `Model` object using following code snippet to generate URL. If it exceeds length limitation, which would cause above error.

```
"url": '@Url.Action("AjaxListOfAudits", "Client", Model)'
```

If you'd like to pass both `_AuditDTGridViewModel` and server-side processing parameters to your action, please refer to the following example code to pass them from request body.

*On JS client*

```
var oTable = $('#datatab').DataTable({
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "type": "POST",
        "url": '@Url.Action("AjaxListOfAudits", "Client")',
        "contentType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: function (d) {
            //console.log(@Json.Serialize(Model));

            var _auditDTGridViewModel = @Json.Serialize(Model);
            var ajaxAuditsModel = {
                "_AuditDTGridViewModel": _auditDTGridViewModel, "DTParameters": d
            };

            //console.log(ajaxAuditsModel);

            return JSON.stringify(ajaxAuditsModel);
        }
    },

    // other options
});
```

*In controller action*

```
public JsonResult AjaxListOfAudits([FromBody] AjaxAuditsModel ajaxAuditsModel)
{

    // Some codes go here

}
```

*AjaxAuditsModel Class*

```
public class AjaxAuditsModel
{
    public _AuditDTGridViewModel _AuditDTGridViewModel { get; set; }
    public DTParameters DTParameters { get; set; }
}
```

*Test Result*

[image]